# Phpminiadmin - Add new table

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am using phpminiadmin to access database UI of my project for live site. I want to add new table in my database but not getting any option to add new table.

Is any one knows how to add new table or create a copy of template of exiting table in phphminiadmin ?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the sufficient rights to do so.

Comment: Yeah Epodax, I don't have sufficient rights. It seems I need to create it using query. And ahh..you added tag phpmyadmin. But actually my question is related to phpminiadmin.

Comment: My apologies, I've never heard of phpminiadmin and since SO didn't have a tag with it either I assumed that it was a typo (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can create table using query as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name column_type);
```

Now, we will create following table in TUTORIALS database.

```
tutorials_tbl(
tutorial_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
tutorial_author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
submission_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY ( tutorial_id )
);
```

NOTE: table name `tutorials_tbl` is taken as example

Answer (score 0):

You may find it under operations tab

http://prntscr.com/7cxznm

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is related to Phpminiadmin.